# Polynomial division $p(x) = x^4-(2m + 4)x^2 + (m-2)^2$

Tags: polynomials

For which values of $m$ can the polynomial $p(x) = x^4-(2m + 4)x^2 + (m -2)^2$ be factored into two non-constant polynomials whose coefficients are integers?

Comment: Is that $x^{4100000}$?

Comment: What does “” mean?

Comment: @egreg: Where do you see “”?

Comment: @rubik I see a square depicted next to $x^4$ and the second $m$. But It's probably some spurious character: it seems to be U+100000 (from Private Use area). Maybe one sees it depending on the browser.

Comment: @egreg: That's weird... I think you should remove them, if that's the case.

Comment: Very similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081652/solve-p-4x-x4-−2m-4x2-m−22-such-that-p-4-is-a-product-of-two/1081683#1081683

Answer (score 1):

Let's set $x^2 = y$. Then we have $y^2-(2m+4)y+(m-2)^2$. Let's factor this.

$$y = \frac{2m+4}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{(2m+4)^2-4(m-2)^2}}{2}.$$

Expanding a bit and factoring out the $2$...

$$\begin{align*}
y &= m+2 \pm \sqrt{m^2+4m+4-(m^2-4m+4)} \\
 &= m+2 \pm \sqrt{8m}.
\end{align*}$$

It's evident that the term under the radical must be a perfect square. Given that $8=2^3$, it should be easy to find the remaining solutions!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the polynomial only has even powers. So, set $t = x^2$ to get
$$p(t) = t^2 - 2(m + 2)t + (m - 2)^2$$

Applying the quadratic formula on $p(t)$ you get
$$t = m + 2 \pm \sqrt{8m} = m + 2 \pm 2\sqrt{2m}$$

Then you have
$$p(x) = (x^2 - m - 2 - 2\sqrt{2m})(x^2 - m - 2 + 2\sqrt{2m})$$

For $p(x)$ to have integer coefficients, $\sqrt{2m}$ has to be a positive integer, and that occurs when $m = 2k^2$, with $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Note that with $m = 0$ you get two coincident solutions.

Comment: $m=0$ would also work. There is no requirement of *distinct* polynomial factors.

Comment: @Arkamis: Yeah, I was puzzled about the "non-constant" part. There is no way the factor can be constant, so I assumed it somehow meant that the factors had to be distinct.

Comment: "Non-constant" usually means no polynomials of order 0, i.e. $k \cdot \frac{1}{k} P(x)$ doesn't count.

Comment: @Arkamis: I've edited my answer, thanks for the correction.

Comment: What? Why did I get downvoted?

Comment: Who knows, but judging from my own recent downvote history, it's probably one of the many users that choose to act anti-socially. I wouldn't sweat it.

Comment: In any case, have an upvote to compensate.

Comment: @Arkamis: That's unfortunate... Anyway, I returned the favour.